# Passing props to already rendered component

Tags: reactjs

I need to pass new props to a reactjs component which I have already rendered using ReactDOM.render method, so doing something like this

```
function callback(d) {
    var data = d || defaultData;
    ReactDOM.render(<MyComp data={data} />, document.getElementById('con'));
}
callback();

setTimeout(function() {
   var newData = ...;
   callback(newData);
}, 10000);
```

Comment: When you receive the new data, set it on the components state by calling call `setState()` and the component will automatically re-render.

If you're using redux, then update the redux store and the component will automatically re-render.

Comment: I am using it in some 3rd party application, which allows me to render React component only inside its callback method, and whenever new data is available app called the callback method again with new data.

Comment: Ok, so right now calling `callback()` after `setTimeout` doesn't update the data? i..e after 10 seconds?

Comment: Actually it does :), I just want to check whether its the correct approach?

Comment: Well, if the data being passed to the component is used elsewhere as well, then its a good idea to use redux*, If not you can store the data in Parent components state or directly on the child components state.